# BinaryField vs TextField

Tags: django, django-orm, django-models

In Django what are the reasons to use `BinaryField` vs `TextField`?

Some questions I have:

- Can I store `binary` data in a `TextField`? What happens if I put arbitrary binary data in the field?
- In the cases of pure text, what are the advantages of a `TextField`? Is it just that when I use the field I avoid having to `base64` encode/decode the data?

Answer (score -2):

Use `binary` when the sizes of the column data entries are consistent, data is simply a stream of bits and store a maximum of 8,000 bytes in the form of bits.

User `text` when to store large texts in your database, when you don't need to implement search on this column and don't make joins this column to other.

Just google it, you will find thousand of answers.